# Running A regex replace infinite times

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm currently working on a file that has a lot of duplicate lines splattered across the file and I'm trying to remove those duplicates. I tried using `replace-regexp` with `\(.+^J\)\(\(.+^J\)+?\)\1+` => `\1\2` which is working okay. Then I realised that there'll be some lines not caught by that so I captured it in a macro. But now I'm stuck running that several times and not knowing if/when it'll ever be done.

I get the feeling I should be able to use some sort of function to do this but I'm not entirely sure how. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Replace Regexp will work on the region, run `mark-whole-buffer` before you run it to make sure it covers the whole buffer. I have never seen `replace-regexp` miss something it should have replaced, if that is really happening it's a bug.

Comment: @jordonbiondo sometimes a regexp replace will create a new string that matches the original regexp. Eg, search & replace two spaces with one space: if the original has four spaces in a row, the replacement will be two spaces. Silly example, but I occasionally run into similar problems with real regexps.

Comment: Example: HereIsAFirstRow
HereIsASecondRow
HereIsAFirstRow
HereIsASecondRow

Running the regex will create HereIsAFirstRow HereIsASecondRow HereIsASecondRow which can be matched by the regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a simpler function than regex?

```
M-x delete-duplicate-lines
```

is often what I use. It is a function in sort.el.gz. If there is a special reason for keeping/retaining one copy of the duplicate line (say you want to keep the last one but delete all others), then you may want to explore repeatable macros with regex conditions.

Comment: Infuriatingly, the copy of emacs that I have at work is 23.3.1 so that function isn't available to me :-(

However, I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a macro endlessly till the first error occurs (like reaching the end of buffer) by passing it a `0` prefix. Using the default keyboard macro binding, that would be `M-0 F4`.